# war file generated is not working in control server in netbeans maven project

Tags: maven

my MAVEN project is running properly in my local server.when I try to generate the war file it is only 4 M.B which is to less because my project war file is 24 M.B when created in another machine. But in my machine it is creating only 4 M.B war file.when i try to deploy the 4 M.B file in the control server it is not deploying.my net beans-6.9(64 bit),tomcat 6 and java 6 .

Comment: `is to less because my project war file is 24 M.B ` Why don't you use project war then? `it is not deploying` Would you mind to describe what exactly is happening, currently your question is practically unanswerable.

Comment: when i build in netbeans 6.9 i am getting 24 m.b war file but same project when i build in net beans 7.2 it is generating 4 m.b war file

Comment: my project is maven build.

Comment: Please, edit your question. You should include details: 1. maven version used to build first (24MB) war; 2. maven version used to build second (4MB) war; 3. differences between those archives (unpack and compare); 4. *relevant* parts of pom xml; 5. error message displayed on deploy.

Comment: maven version same maven 3.2.3.pom are also same.error message is false when deployed on server